# Can I use Ubuntu Pro with an interim release?

Tags: 22.10, ubuntu-pro

I bought Ubuntu Pro for my Ubuntu Desktop 22.10. I first reached out to official Ubuntu sales departement as apparently Ubuntu Pro is not compatible with 22.10. They replied and said this:
The machine is compatible. I just cannot provide you with technical support to set it up. I'm sorry!

Anyone has more information about how to set it up?

Comment: To set expectations: Pro is a commercial service from Canonical. We're a bunch of volunteers. What specifically do you need help setting up? The computer is all running okay? Or you have a specific issue? Can you edit the post and detail the specific thing you're after please?

Comment: @popey I think he's looking for the command to enroll the system in Pro which is explicitly shown in the licensing page once they've purchased Pro

Comment: Note that we rewrote the question slightly to point to *any* interim release, not just 22.10, and my answer in-depth answers the specific question of "can you use Ubuntu Pro" vs. "What do you get with ubuntu pro on non LTS releases" because they're related answers/questions and is better detailed here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Ubuntu Pro **is for LTS versions of Ubuntu only** and does not provide any benefits for non-LTS releases.

This is evidenced by attaching your system to Ubuntu Pro as detailed below in the section about it, and then running `sudo pro status --all` to get output like this about what is available for you under that subscription.  We can compare LTS vs. non-LTS status entitlements and what's available for each here:

**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS System**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ sudo pro status --all
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
cc-eal           yes       n/a       Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
fips             yes       n/a       NIST-certified core packages
fips-updates     yes       n/a       NIST-certified core packages with priority security updates
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
ros              yes       n/a       Security Updates for the Robot Operating System
ros-updates      yes       n/a       All Updates for the Robot Operating System
usg              yes       n/a       Security compliance and audit tools

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: <snip>
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

**Ubuntu 22.10 non-LTS System**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic

$ sudo pro status --all
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
cc-eal           yes       n/a       Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
cis              yes       n/a       Security compliance and audit tools
esm-apps         yes       n/a       Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       n/a       Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
fips             yes       n/a       NIST-certified core packages
fips-updates     yes       n/a       NIST-certified core packages with priority security updates
livepatch        yes       n/a       Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       n/a       Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
ros              yes       n/a       Security Updates for the Robot Operating System
ros-updates      yes       n/a       All Updates for the Robot Operating System

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: <snip>
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

As you can see, only the LTS releases are entitled to anything in Ubuntu Pro, so your 22.10 system gains no benefit from a Pro subscription.

---

**To attach your system to a Pro subscription, though...**

Despite the limitation of Pro only being for LTS, go to your Pro dashboard at https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard and you will have your subscriptions listed.  You click your subscription and the info on the right side changes to it.  Where you see Token and Documentation, it shows you the command to run to attach your system to Ubuntu Pro - which is `sudo pro attach TOKEN_HERE`.

This is a screenshot example from *my* Pro dashboard (I use Pro "free" for my expired / old LTS boxes that need ESM but also Livepatch, note that I'm an Ubuntu Member so behind the scenes that "5 Free" is actually *more* machines than 5, but only 5 are reflected here).

---

Note that Pro plans are not all equal!  You get zero support for the 'cheap' Pro entitlement plans on Desktop installs unless you *want* full Canonical tech support in which case it only will work for LTS releases and is $300 per system.  See https://ubuntu.com/pricing/pro for details on what comes with each subscription type/tier.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Pro is available for LTS versions of Ubuntu. 22.10 is not an LTS version, so you can't use it there.

Also Ubuntu Pro is free of charge for individual users.

Your machine may be compatible in the meaning that the hardware can be used with Ubuntu Pro.

Comment: Don't forget kernel livepatching, that's a Pro feature too.  `esm-*` might not work nor will FIPS or such, but there *are* bits in Pro that can be used with non-LTS

Comment: I am not quite sure these bits can really be used, like support.

Comment: Support doesn't exist if you go for the cheapo Pro plan anyways - https://ubuntu.com/pricing/pro - but you're right, more or less everything for Pro doesn't work on LTS except I think maybe livepatch or one of the other offerings.  I'm looking at things right now to poke it and see what 22.10 systems would have available for offerings after attaching.

Comment: I've confirmed (thank you VMs!) that Pro does not work on interim-OSes.  It doesn't stop you from *attaching* a non-LTS to a Pro subscription, but you don't get anything despite being entitled to things (see my answer for comparative output - this is due to those 'offerings' not being available for non-LTS releases), and I mention that in my answer which more completely answers OP's question of how to actually attach the 22.10 system to Pro despite getting no benefits